# How do I pass a rect into pygame.display.update() to update a specific area of the window?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

On the [documentation page](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) for `pygame.display.update()`, it says you can pass a rect into the method to update part of the screen. However, all of the examples I see just pass an existing rect from an image or shape in the program. How can I tell it to update an area on the screen directly? For example, when drawing a rectangle, I could use a rect argument of `(100,200,30,40)`. This would draw a rectangle with a top at 200, a left at 100, a width of 30, and a height of 40. How can I pass a similar argument into `pygame.display.update()`? I tried `pygame.display.update((100,200,30,40))`, but this updates the entire window.

Comment: @MichealO'Dwyer Of course I have. I'm not asking you to write my code - I just need to know how to pass an argument to a very specific command. `pygame.display.update((100,200,30,40))` is failing to only update only the area I'm trying to update, so I assume I am not passing the rect correctly.

Comment: @MichealO'Dwyer I understand that you don't want to answer questions from people who don't do their work, but I feel that it should be obvious from the specificity of my question that I have been working on this for a while and have narrowed the problem down to a single line of code. That said, I have added a specific example to the question that describes my problem more precisely, so it is easier to answer.

Comment: I saw that you edited it to include an attempt :)
I would've answered but there is a perfect answer below already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just define a [rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and pass it to [`pygame.display.update()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) to update only this specific region of the display. You can also pass a list of rects.

```
import random

import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


# A simple sprite, just to have something moving on the screen.
class Ball(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, screen_rect):
        super().__init__()
        radius = random.randrange(5, 31)
        self.image = pg.Surface((radius*2, radius*2), pg.SRCALPHA)
        pg.draw.circle(self.image, pg.Color('dodgerblue1'), (radius, radius), radius)
        pg.draw.circle(self.image, pg.Color('dodgerblue3'), (radius, radius), radius-2)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)
        self.vel = Vector2(random.uniform(-2, 2), random.uniform(-2, 2))
        self.pos = Vector2(self.rect.center)
        self.screen_rect = screen_rect
        self.lifetime = 350

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos

        self.lifetime -= 1
        if not self.screen_rect.contains(self.rect) or self.lifetime <= 0:
            self.kill()


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    screen.fill((20, 40, 70))
    pg.display.update()
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    # Pass this rect to `pg.display.update` to update only this area.
    update_rect = pg.Rect(50, 50, 500, 400)

    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

        all_sprites.add(Ball(screen_rect))
        all_sprites.update()

        screen.fill((20, 50, 90))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        # Update only the area that we specified with the `update_rect`.
        pg.display.update(update_rect)
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. I tried your exact code with pygame 2.0.0 (SDL 2.0.12, python 3.7.8) and it does not work the way it looks in your video. It updates the complete screen. No Cliping effect like in your video. Is it a version problem?