# pygame.display.update updates the entire screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a multiplayer game with splitted screen.

I start by drawing the first player on the left-hand side (spaceship, fire bombs, stars in the background (scrolling at half speed) and finally the background), then I update the first part of the screen, for the first player. Then I do the same things for the second player, on the other part of the screen.

But most of the images overlap thoughout the two half-screens. (see image below)

So, basically I need to update one part of the screen using `pygame.display.update()`, then the other part.

But the command doesn’t work, and updates the entire screen. And everything overlaps.

#### I've tried the following:

`pygame.display.update(Rect((pos, 0), size))`

`pygame.display.update(Rect((pos, 0, size[0], size[1])))`

`pygame.display.update((pos, 0, size[0], size[1]))`

`pygame.display.update(pos, 0, size[0], size[1])`

`pygame.display.update((pos, 0), size)`

**But all of these are doing exactly the same thing, and they don't work as expected.**

[image: Rendering]

Comment: Update takes an optional rect argument `pygame.display.update(rect_to_update)`. in the event nothing is passed, it updates everything. `update` should also generally only be called once at the end of the game loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a rect into pygame.display.update() to update a specific area of the window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48711791/how-do-i-pass-a-rect-into-pygame-display-update-to-update-a-specific-area-of-t)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314987/difference-between-pygame-display-update-and-pygame-display-flip

Comment: **Sorry, I missed to say that I've tried to use Rect. On pygame 1.9.6 it works, but on pygame 2.0.0 it doesn't works. I'll "update" my question.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using `pygame.display.update()` there are two kinds of an **optional** argument, single rect (which defaults to None) and a list of rects. If no argument is passed, it updates the entire surface area - like display.flip() does.

```
update(rectangle=None) -> None
update(rectangle_list) -> None
```

To update only specific elements, either create a list of these elements if you want to update the same group at the same time

```
background_rects = [star_rect, star_rect, star_rect, some_other_rect]
foreground_rects = [player_rect, enemy1_rect, enemy2_rect, bullet1_rect, bullet2_rect]
pygame.display.update(background_rects)
pygame.display.update(foreground_rects)
```

or call `update(rect)` multiple times with the individual elements:

```
pygame.display.update(star1_rect)
pygame.display.update(star2_rect)
pygame.display.update(star3_rect)
pygame.display.update(character_rect)
pygame.display.update(enemy_rect)
```

Link to the documentation: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update

There seems to be some (probably unintended as there is nothing about it in the docs) difference between the handling of pygame 1.9.6 and the 2.0.0.dev branches - below is a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which works with 1.9.6, but not with the 2.0.0.**dev10** version. In 1.9.6 the difference in updating the display is easily visible. I suggest you install the **stable** 1.9.6 version if you need this exact functionality!

In case others want to try their luck, here is the MRE with which I tested:

```
import pygame
import time    
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 480)) 

rect = pygame.Rect((10, 50), (32, 32))  
image = pygame.Surface((32, 32)) 
image.fill((0,100,0))

rect2 = pygame.Rect((10, 10), (32, 32)) 
image2 = pygame.Surface((32, 32)) 
image2.fill((100,100,0))

i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
            
    screen.blit(image, rect)
    screen.blit(image2, rect2)
    rect.x += 1 # we update the position every cycle
    rect2.x += 1  # we update the position every cycle
    
    # but update the rect on screen at different times:
    if i < 10:
        pygame.display.update() # both
    elif i > 50 and i < 75:
        pygame.display.update(rect2) # only rect2 
    elif i >= 100:
        pygame.display.update(rect) # only rect

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: I'll try to put some 1.9.6 code in 2.0.0 code because I need som pygame 2.0.0 skills: joystick updating, better speed and the flag `SCALED`...

Comment: I'm sorry, but this solution didn't work until I upgraded `pygame` to 2.0.1. This issue was caused by a bug and not because I wasn't passing a `Rect` as an argument. I took a look at this question and I think I will delete the question, or add an answer related to the `pygame` bug fixes.

Comment: But your answer works for other users who have the same problem as described in the answers whose question has been associated - so I will leave the post.