# Two arcs while using Pygame tranform.flip

Tags: pygame, automatic-ref-counting, draw

This is my first real code project. I am trying to create a Crash gambling project for a math project at School.

My current problem is that when I flip my arc it draws 2 separate arcs. I don't know why it does this but if anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
from math import sin, cos, radians

grid = pygame.image.load('grid3.jpg')
wn = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
wn2 = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
r = 600
a = 0
b = 0

def x_y(r, i, a, b):
  return (int(r * cos(radians(i)) + a), int(r * sin(radians(i)) + b))
for i in range(0, 90, 1): 
  clock.tick(30)
  pygame.draw.line(wn, (255, 255, 255), x_y(r, i, a, b), x_y(r, i+1, a, b), 10)
  wn2.blit(wn, (0,0))
  wn.blit(grid,(0,0))
  wn2.blit(pygame.transform.rotate(wn2, -90), (0, 0))
  wn = pygame.transform.flip(wn2, True, False)
  pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you draw onto a [display `Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode), it won't remove the other existing elements. Take this code as an example:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 240))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), Rect(50, 20, 100, 100))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), Rect(120, 100, 100, 100))
pygame.display.flip() # same as pygame.display.update() (with no arguments)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
```

When executing this, you will see 2 squares appear, the second one being drawn not preventing the first one from still appearing, even though you `update`d the screen.

[image]

As a display surface is also a transparent surface, `blit`ting a display Surface onto another will not erase its content.
To do that, you can call the [`Surface.fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) function.

---

A few optional (but some I recommend) improvements to your code:

- Implement a [game loop](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-up-the-game-loop-in-pyggame) to your game/simulation to namely get the user events and preventing your game from constantly crashing after a while
- Use `pygame.display.flip()` instead of `pygame.display.update()` (the latter is useful when you want to only update [part of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63391103/pygame-display-update-updates-the-entire-screen))
- You are creating 2 screen surfaces, but that's not possible. `wn` and `wn2` are referring to the same surface. Use [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) for creating other surfaces.
- Try to leave the main display surface as it is, and work with other surfaces rather than changing the entire screen by `transform`ing it, as this can be confusing when debugging.

I hope that helped!